# Where's the Block Template Feature in WordPress?

Tags: block-editor, content

I'm working on developing a site for one of the Institutes under our organizational umbrella, and I've run into a situation where it'd be great to have a template with some blocks already in place that a user could add and then replace the placeholders with the relevant information. If you've used Joomla and Regular Labs' Content Templater extension, you know exactly what I'm talking about.

I thought this was a feature in Wordpress, but I'm either missing something obvious or it's not there. I know there's the reusable blocks feature, which is close. You have to convert to regular blocks first before editing the content, but this is prone to user error and I'd rather reduce the number of steps required to get the template onto the page and ready for the user's content.

I've tried looking, but the only thing I keep finding is the Site Editor that's in Beta, and not what I'm after. It seems like this would be such an obvious thing to have built in, I'm a little baffled that I can't find anything like it besides Reusable Blocks.

Comment: I think Block Templates is what you want: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-templates/ If you lock templates as per the Locking section you should get the behaviour you want.

Comment: @JacobPeattie - I saw that, but I was looking for a method similar to the reusable blocks. Select a group of blocks and set as a template. As far as I have been able to find, the only way, currently, is to do it though the theme, which in my case causes issues.

Comment: You should switch to full site editing theme. There you can define templates like you described and even very easily hardcode such templates by copying whole site content and pasting into html file in templates directory. Of course, you can have template just in database or modify existing templates without coding - modifications are WYSIWYG based in editor and saved to database.

Comment: @Lovor - That's what I was afraid of. I'm not really allowed to do that. We are part of a university that has all websites for organizations under its umbrella use a specific template that Strategic Communications maintains. I don't really have any control or say-so over what capabilities that theme has, including using the site editor.